# Using @Test and expected

Tags: junit, junit4

in my Junit tests I have a test case that must be fail only when IOexception is throwing by my object under test.

So ,if my object under test throw IllegalStateException (or other Error or Exception)  my test case is OK but if my object under test throw IOexception my test case must be fail.

How can I do it ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the expected exception rule

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException expected = new ExpectedException();


@Test
public void doSomethingWithNoIOException() {
    // we expect an exception that's NOT an instance of IOException
    // you'll need to static import the hamcrest matchers referenced below
    expected.expect(not(instanceOf(IOException.class));

    // call the method under test
    callSomething();
}
```

Comment: I know this, but what is the advantage that we get by using this approach, so I prefer mine as it looks pretty simple ? I think it is fully opinion based and we can follow either of the approaches

Comment: It looks like you're trying to start an argument. The above uses the test frameworks. An alternative with try/catch tends to work outside of the test framework. My preference would be to use AssertJ where you can have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

**As you want to fail when exception is NOT an IOException, You can do that by catching the `IOException` and asserting with `fail()` like below:**

```
@Test
public void yourTestScenario() {
    try { 
      //code that throws IOException and other Exceptions
    } catch(IOException ioexe) {
        Assert.fail();
    } catch(Exception exe) {
       //Ignore
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is an antipattern. You can use JUnit or AssertJ to verify exceptions thrown.

Comment: Did you question clearly ? He wants a NOT IOException condition, not an expected condition and both he wants to handle in a single method

Comment: Please see my proposed answer. It's tempting to use try/catch in test methods, but it's probably not the best answer.